# How to activate Cycles reporting in Instruments under ARC?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

Instruments can visualize retain cycles under ARC in a graphically interesting way. I also remember that a few days ago I spotted the "Cycles" view in Instruments by accident.

Now where I started using ARC, suddenly I'm not able to find that anymore. The Allocations and VM Tracker instruments don't offer it, and the Leaks instrument either.

What must I do in order to see retain cycles?

Found a screenshot as evidence:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Xcode 4.2.1, I found the it in "Leaks", under "Cycles & Roots".  However, I've found it less than useful when using ARC.  It does detect CF leaks and apparently I'm leaking a recursive block, which I can't do anything about, but I've had to root out several retain cycles that Leaks never found.  For finding retain cycles, I recommend using "Allocations" and running several heap shots between performing the action you suspect of 'leaking'. You then then look through the interim heap shots to find the culprit.

Comment: So that only appears in Xcode > 4.2? I don't have Lion and just 4.2, but I'm absolutely sure I've spotted "Cycles" already in Xcode. Just can't activate it anymore. It disappeared.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if it's available in less that 4.2.1, but it's not been useful.  I had a huge retain cycle where two view controllers were retaining themselves (forgot to use __weak), and they had lots of images.  Leaks never detected it.  Very annoying, so now I use Allocations more.

Comment: @MikhaloIvanokov - It is in Xcode 4.2, just under the Leaks instrument. You have to click the pulldown in the lower panel to the left of the "Leak Cycles" wording in your image above, and change the value from "Leaks" to "Cycles & Roots".

Comment: @AaronHayman - If you can assemble a test case for this, file a bug report on the behavior with that case. This is fairly new technology, and I know the Leaks instrument was designed to be conservative, so they very well could be missing something. They seem to be improving ARC and related tools pretty quickly lately, so this might help them address that.

Comment: Found it! But really, I looked into this exact spot many times and there was nothing. It seems to appear on a somewhat random basis.

Comment: Cycles reporting is only supported in projects that use ARC, that may explain why you see it come and go (if you are in different projects).

Comment: Anybody find this with recent / 6.3 builds?  The apple docs still show it.  I am using a mixed / Swift project, but don't see any means of expanding the items in the leftmost column.