# Detecting/Fixing Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've finished coding my project, but then when I have submitted my source code in the client, it was tested, then memory leaks were detected. I have tested in `Instruments using Leaks`. 
What I am having problem with is in my `AVPlayer` and in my `AVAudioPlayer` and something in my `AppDelegate`.
Should I find an alternate on this? or there's something wrong with my code?

Here is my code below(I am using `ARC` by the way):

--->**AppDelegate**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RootViewAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

AND

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

--->**AVPlayer**

```
self.moviePlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
```

--->**AVAudioPlayer**

```
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/Normal.wav"];
NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
NSError* err;

//Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
BGMplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

if( err ){
    //bail!
    NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    //set our delegate and begin playback
    BGMplayer.delegate = self;
    [BGMplayer play];
    BGMplayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    BGMplayer.currentTime = 0;
    BGMplayer.volume = 1.0;
}
```

Here is how I detect those above:

[image]

---

Hope someone would help me, this is kinda my first time detecting memory leaks. So I hope for your guidance. THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Comment: Can you show more code? I want to see if you set references to nil when not using the object anymore.

Comment: As others suggested, try Xcode's static code analyzer. Another good idea would be Instruments' retain cycle detector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852451/how-to-activate-cycles-reporting-in-instruments-under-arc

Comment: Yes i have used static analyzer. But i dont know why it wasnt appearing.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri what codes do want to see? The code of the class that was in the above mentioned

Comment: have you tried setting the delegate to nil in the removeFromSuperview method ?

Comment: @HotLicks analyzer? within xcode? i set it to yes, but still no `potential leaks` appear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should Analyze your Code by shift+Command+B key combination hope it will tell your memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that with

```
//set our delegate and begin playback
BGMplayer.delegate = self;
```

AVPlayer retains your view, and since your view also retains the AVPlayer you got a retain circle that prevents both from beeing released by arc.

I'd suggest setting the delegate to nil when it is not longer needed... perhaps by overwriting `removeFromSuperview` in your view.

Add the following to your view:

```
- (void)removeFromSuperview {
    BGMplayer.delegate = nil;
    [super removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: in `viewDidDisappear`? How about the `moviePlayer`?

Comment: how to overwrite the `removeFromSuperview`?

Comment: ok .. that only works in a UIView, not in a UIViewController. Why do you need to set the delegate in the first place ? You could try without the `BGMplayer.delegate = self` line if you don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like some of your instance variables are not being released. I think, your `moviePlayer` property is retaining the `AVPlayer` object and you are not releasing it in `dealloc` (maybe some other instance variable). Hope this helps.