# avplayer memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an Intro movie in my project when the app starts, I'm using `storyboard` by the way, then I make my `MovieVC` as the Initial View, so when the app starts, the `MovieVC` is shown then when you pressed or the movie ends, it will present the `RootVC`. Its working in `simulator` and `device` when I tested it, but when I test it with `instruments` using `Leaks`, memory leaks were discovered.

I don't know what's wrong,  Im using ARC, but I think my `moviePlayer` isn't being release or my the problem is in the `ViewControllers`.

Here is my code for my `MovieVC`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gameopening" ofType:@"m4v"];
    self.moviePlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
    [self.moviePlayer play];

    // Create and configure AVPlayerLayer
    AVPlayerLayer *moviePlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.moviePlayer];
    moviePlayerLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    moviePlayerLayer.position = CGPointMake(515,385);
    moviePlayerLayer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    moviePlayerLayer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    moviePlayerLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    moviePlayerLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.80;

    // Add perspective transform

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:moviePlayerLayer];    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(loadingView) withObject:nil afterDelay:33.0];  
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UIImageView *loadingView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; 
        loadingView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Load.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
        [self performSelector:@selector(mainV) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];  
    }

}
-(void)loadingView{

        UIImageView *loadingView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];  
        loadingView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Load.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
        [self performSelector:@selector(mainV) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];  

}
-(void)mainV {

        moviePlayer = nil;
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainViewController"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];   
}
```

Hope someone will help on what I am doing wrong. Thankyou.

Comment: add [super viewDidLoad] on top of viewDidLoad method and remove unwanted [super viewDidLoad] line as u have used twice.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly Instruments says leaked?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I have used the intrument `Leaks` , here is my other question connected to this--->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581164/detecting-fixing-memory-leaks

Comment: @Superman I understand that you are using Leaks. What objects are being leaked?

Comment: @Prince, have done what you have said, then I tested it in the intruments, still leaks though. :(

Comment: @Superman that's extremely vague. Can you specify what objects *that your code instantiated* are being leaked? Also - are your clients really objecting a 48 byte leak? How many times is it being leaked?

Comment: @CarlVeazey its the `self.moviePlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];` part, only in the beginning it is being leaked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17168/discussion-between-carl-veazey-and-superman)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest try running the instrument using device... as previous there was some problem with the library itself.
If on device the leak disappear then you are good to go.. :)