# instruments - #living + arc

Tags: ios, ios6, automatic-ref-counting, instruments, allocation

My application has 2 view controllers.
The first one has only one button to call the second view controller full of animations.
While running instruments with allocations, it starts with 12000 in the #living slot.
After dismissing the second view controller the #living count never returns to 12000 again. It keeps 18000. In the third pass it goes up to 24000.
I am using iOS 6 and arc.
Shouldn't arc take care of freeing memory?
Any clues about these extra 6000 every time I dismiss the second view controller and, supposedly, everything inside it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ARC handles the *retain* and *release* for you.  It does not prevent, detect or resolve cycles - that is, where any object A retains B which also retains A (or any variation thereof, with longer chains of objects).  Rather than you or I guessing where this comes from, you can use Instruments to find the cycle(s) - see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852451/how-to-activate-cycles-reporting-in-instruments-under-arc) earlier Stackoverflow post.  There's also lots of reading material out there on the Interwebs about retain cycles (e.g. [Mike Ash's blog](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-30-dealing-with-retain-cycles.html)).